# Zoom in on windows powershell without a mouse or trackpad (just keyboard/menu)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, remote-desktop

I am attempting to zoom in on Windows PowerShell and the recommended way is by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + [mouse wheel up](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-console-ctrl-scroll-to-zoom-and-dark-theme-scrollbar/)

But I'm using a trackpad on a Mac via a remote desktop session, so is there any keyboard input, menu setting (or anything else) I can use to zoom in in place of the mouse wheel / trackpad method?

Comment: If you use the Powershell ISE you can zoom in and out with CTRL + + and CTRL + -. But then you have to use the ISE...

Answer (score 3):

A few things that might help would be...

- **Right-click** on the *title bar* and select **Properties**

  [image]
- Go to the **Font** tab, type in a larger number into the **Size** field, and press **OK**

  [image]
- Afterwards type in `cls` to the PowerShell terminal window and press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> to clear the screen.
- Press <kbd>**`Alt`**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> to toggle the PowerShell terminal in and out of full screen too.
- Lastly, you can adjust the **Layout** tab **Window Size** fields for **Width** and **Height** to accommodate your visual accordingly from the *title bar* **Properties** as well.

  [image]

Comment: The link you provided shows the PowerShell terminal and not ISE so I assume you are referring to the PowerShell command terminal window only.